# How do I add a logged-in users profile pic to the wordpress top-bar/menu-bar on my wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the buddypress plugin, along with a few others, on my wordpress site which I built using the OceanWP theme. I wanted for my users to have their profile picture show on the top bar menu when they are logged in, similar to this:
http://prntscr.com/qcuyri

I have created an item on the menu bar with a drop down list which appears when you hover over it. It is currently named "profile" but I wanted it to show the users profile picture instead of the word "profile".

I found some code online which, i believe, should fetch the profile picture of buddypress users using "get_avatar".

I have placed the following code in the index.php folder:

```
<?php
       global $current_user;
       get_currentuserinfo();     
       echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 64 );
?>
```

but when I type get_avatar in the navigation label of the item:
http://prntscr.com/qcuxh0

...it just changes the name of the item to "get_avatar" instead of showing the profile pic on front end:
http://prntscr.com/qcuxxs

I was wondering if anybody could advise what I would need to type in the navigation label so it would display the users profile pic instead or whether there are any changes which are needed in the code as well?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using: pass the current user email id in get_avatar() function if user is logged in

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) 
     {
        echo 'Welcome : ' . esc_html( $current_user->display_name );
        echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 32 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Neal Developer , thank you very much for this! I have pasted the code in my index.php file but I was just wondering what I would need to type in the navigation field, in the menu item, so that the profile picture shows up in the menu bar?

Comment: Yes you need to paste this where you need to show up. check this as resolved if it works

Comment: sorry about this but I'm a little confused, the code which you posted, so that doesn't go in the Index.php file?

Comment: You can place it where you need to show the image. you can test it with place that code !

Comment: really sorry but I pasted the code in a code block in a post but it just displays the code on the front end. I really not sure if there is anything I should have added before or at the end of it, I am a beginner u see. But the thing is that I wanted the image to be shown in the menu bar, in a menu item, and the navigation label in the item doesn't accept code. Does this mean I cannot achieve this using this method?

Comment: @Jas You no need to past these code into the code editor you have to paste it in the files where menu are calling Or you have to create custom menu design as per your shared screenshot

Comment: if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) 
     { ?>
           <img src="<?php echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 32 ); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
}

Answer (score 0):

The following short tags to the menu link: `{first_name}` `{last_name}` `{username}` `{nickname}`. To use this feature you simply add the short tags to the menu item’s navigation label like so:

[image]

**To Show user profile photo in menu**

You can also show the user’s profile photo in the menu using the **short tag**: `{user_avatar_small}`. If you add this tag into the navigation label field the profile photo for the user will show.

[image]

I have a spical way to add class to image or styling using css. by adding `{user_avatar_small}` into span like this :

```
<span class="your-class">{user_avatar_small}</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Insert this code to call the avatar of the current user, please have a look as below:

```
<?php
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( $user ) : ?>
   <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_avatar_url( $user->ID ) ); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm lost! lol. Thanks a lot for this but if I paste this in my index.php file how does the code know where to display the profile image? do I need to put anything in the navigation label here: https://prnt.sc/qcuxh0 ??

Comment: @Jas, you no need to paste this in index.php, you have to customize code in header.php and call the primary menu then paste about code there

Comment: Ahh I see. Ok I think this involves more knowledge than I have so I think i'm gonna have to research this a bit more or post another question. Thanks for all your help though, mate!!

Comment: Thanks, @Jas if you will have any query or concern then please feel free to ask